# d3js svg water droplet or teardrop

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

My goal is to draw a single water droplet with d3js.

EDIT: Another example here offers the correct shape: 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1020902 , but playing with the code.

They use the `superformula` plugin for d3 on [github here](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/superformula/superformula.js), which looks like another good nudge.

```
var _superformulaTypes = {
    drop: {m: 1, n1: .5, n2: .5, n3: .5, a: 1, b: 1}
  };
```

Using math to draw shapes with svg & d3 makes anything possible, see [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3094619), from Mike Bostock (the Twitter logo):

```
<svg viewBox="328 355 335 276" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="
    M 630, 425
    A 195, 195 0 0 1 331, 600
    A 142, 142 0 0 0 428, 570
    A  70,  70 0 0 1 370, 523
    A  70,  70 0 0 0 401, 521
    A  70,  70 0 0 1 344, 455
    A  70,  70 0 0 0 372, 460
    A  70,  70 0 0 1 354, 370
    A 195, 195 0 0 0 495, 442
    A  67,  67 0 0 1 611, 380
    A 117, 117 0 0 0 654, 363
    A  65,  65 0 0 1 623, 401
    A 117, 117 0 0 0 662, 390
    A  65,  65 0 0 1 630, 425
    Z"
    style="fill:#3BA9EE;"/>
</svg>
```

Likewise, Ian Johnson creates [various shapes](http://tributary.io/inlet/4942307) here:

My goal is to create 1 simple teardrop shape.  Anything that looks more like a water droplet or teardrop would get me started, thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to generate it from a formula? You could just draw an svg path in a vector editing tool and use it.

Comment: There will be many of these droplets.  Imagine a typical heatmap, where the rect's are replaced with water 'drop'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use a simple path and change its size and position with transforms:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr({width: 400, height: 400});

var dropPath = 'M 243.44676,222.01677 C 243.44676,288.9638 189.17548,343.23508 122.22845,343.23508 C 55.281426,343.23508 1.0101458,288.9638 1.0101458,222.01677 C 1.0101458,155.06975 40.150976,142.95572 122.22845,0.79337431 C 203.60619,141.74374 243.44676,155.06975 243.44676,222.01677 z';

var data = d3.range(300).map(function(){ return Math.random()/3; });

svg.selectAll('g.drop').data(data)
 .enter().append('g')
 .attr({
  'class': 'drop', 
  transform: function(d, i){
   return 'translate('+[Math.random()*300, Math.random()*300]+') scale('+d+')';
  }
 })
 .append('path').attr({d: dropPath})
```

```css
svg g.drop path{
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width': 3px;
  fill: skyblue;
  fill-opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that you'd likely want a `sqrt` scale here, not a linear representation of the data.